# Angular 6 - Populating the table content values dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am populating a table from some json data.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let datakeys of listData[0] | keys">{{ datakeys }}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let datavalues of listData | values">
    <td>{{ datavalues.userId }}</td>
    <td>{{ datavalues.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ datavalues.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ datavalues.body }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The first **ngFor** will display all the table headings. Data is held in **datakeys**.

The second **ngFor** contains the values.

At the moment you can see that the keys on the values of **datavalues** are hardcoded.

When I need it to do is to be taken from **datakeys** so it's done be code.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `ngFor` just like you did for headings.

```
   <tr *ngFor="let datavalues of listData | values">
      <td *ngFor="let key of datavalues | keys">
           {{ datavalues[key]}}
      </td>
   </tr>
```